# How to use relay switch

Tags: switches, relay

I have a relay switch. Particularly, [leone SC5-S-DC6V](http://www.leonerelays.com/Upload/Image/Model/SC5/Gallery/SC5withlogo.psd.pdf).

I am a noob who wants to use this relay switch. And I don't know how to operate it. Can someone please help me?

For now, I just want to use it with a 6V DC power supply to change the state of switch.

I'm sorry if the question is stupid(It might be, I know really little about these). If that is the case, can someone suggest some references I should look at?

Comment: Apply 6V to the coil and the relay contact switches. Use the contact like you would a push button.

Comment: Umm. Yes, I tried that. But somehow, it didn't switch. I've not connected anything to other 3 terminals, if that matters. And I am using a multimeter to check the contact after applying voltage to coil.

Comment: It may need to have 6V applied in the correct polarity - try connecting it both ways. Some relays use magnets inside to help the mechanical switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

When the coils is **not powered** pin labelled 1 will be connected to pin labelled 3.

Connect power between connections A and B.

When the coils is **powered** pin labelled 1 will be connected to pin labelled 2.

Make sure the relay is a 6V model. The datasheet shows 12V and 24V models too.

Comment: Yeah, the model is for 6V.

Comment: And, isn't this one a latching relay?

Comment: @nisargjhaveri I see nothing in the datasheet that says it's a latching relay. If you need it to latch you should buy a Double Pole contact type and wire one of the n/o contacts in parallel with your coil power circuit so the relay keeps itself powered on once activated.

Comment: can I apply about 10-12 volts to that switch. What is the tolerance?

Comment: @nisargjhaveri take a look at the Contact Capacity in the Contact Data section of your datasheet. It shows that up to 28V DC at 10A is OK.

Comment: I was talking about coil. Can I use 12V DC to operate switch?

Comment: No. Not if it is a 6V relay.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply only 6V DC to the coil. You can connect AC loads maximum 7A @ 300V AC. You can connect DC loads maximum 10A @ 28V DC and don't exceed the limits.

Comment: The 6V switch works with 5V applied to the coil.